# How to hide Access token and Cient ID when using Javascript SDK?

Tags: oauth-2.0, yammer

This is my first post here. I was exploring the yammer Oen graph and found that I can post on user behalf from my application if I have the Access Token for that user and to generate the access token there is a redirect URL given in documentation. My question is that when I redirect user to this oAUth URL then app id is visible on screen where yammer ask for user credentials and later when Yammer redirects back to my redirect URL then the user access token is very much visible. I see security issue here because App ID and access token are available to end user in query string and in such case this user can use the APP ID and access token to get my app blocked or he can get access token from another user to do it. Any views on it?

Note : I don't want to use server side APIs because that way I can't provide a UI where end user authorize my app to post in yammer.

Answer (score 1):

Users are always able to see their own oauth token, and whatever the user does with the user's oauth token will happen within that user's own context, not your app's context. So don't worry about the user being able to see their own oauth token.

Your app ID is not the same as your app's token that you generate at the end of the oauth setup instructions at https://developer.yammer.com/oauth2-quickstart/. Your app ID can be seen by people without compromising your app. Think of it like the username. It's the token you generate from those instructions that you want to keep private. Think of it like the password.

There's slightly better documentation about this available at https://developer.yammer.com/authentication/#a-requests.